# Vaadin 7.1- Client-side development under Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, vaadin7

I have a GWT web application and I'm interested in adding Vaadin as Jar to my project so I can use their nice widgets.

In order to minimize potential errors, I created a clean GWT web project, added `vaadin-client` and `vaadin-client-compiler` Jars, and inherited `com.vaadin.Vaadin` as explained in [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/clientside.installing.html). I also added the entry point `<inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />` into `myproject.gwt.xml`.

I got the following error when I tried to run the application:

```
Loading inherited module 'com.vaadin.Vaadin'
     [ERROR] The value ie10 was not previously defined.
     [ERROR] Line 64: Unexpected exception while processing element 'set-property'
     com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
```

Thanks

Comment: After posting the same question in Vaadin forums, the error happens due to the existence of two versions of `GWT` in the class path. The vaadin version supports `IE10` while the GWT does not. Although, removing the GWT related `jar` fixed that particular error, but other errors occured in later phases do to missing classes in the vaadin plugin. So, I'll call it a catch 22 situation :-)

Comment: can you tell me the full package name which caused this error?

Comment: @Luma you could probably add the fix as an answer. And a link to Vaadin thread. This one seems to resolve the issue: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3187623